# Optimize a folder for music/video via powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I would like to know the command to set via powershell the option 'optimize this folder for' to 'Music' or whatever on a folder. I didn't find anything approaching in the Attributes list of folder.

Comment: what kind of use case are you looking at? this is way more work than using the GUI. how many folders are you working with? are they all in the same directory? etc.

Comment: They are in the same directory, but it a mapped network drive.It's not applicable directly on the top folder. In the GUI, selecting all the folder and setting 'Music' doesn't work. I would need to go through all of them one by one and they are over 500. That's why I want to do it via script (more fun).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a answer using Powershell, but still better than manual.
Here is the Autohotkey script I used. You have to select the first folder to be modified and pressing F9 will iterate over the number of folders specified.

```
#SingleInstance force
F9::
Loop, 838; The number of folders to be modified

{
    if (GetKeyState("Escape"))
    {
        ExitApp ; To escape if something is wrong
    }
        Send {AppsKey} ; Right click via keyboard
        Send {r} ; go to the properties
        Sleep, 700  ; if it goes to fast, the UI doesn't have the time to actualize
        Send ^{PgDn} ; Jump to Security tab
        Sleep, 700  ;
        Send ^{PgDn} ; Jump to Previous Versions tab
        Sleep, 700  ;
        Send ^{PgDn} ; Jump to Customize
        Sleep, 1000  ;
        Send {Down} ; Switch to Documents
        Sleep, 100  ;
        Send {Down} ; Switch to Pictures
        Sleep, 100  ;
        Send {Down} ; Switch to Music
        Sleep, 500  ;
        Send !s ; Apply this also to subfolders
        Sleep, 100  ;
        Send !a ; Apply
        Sleep, 100  ;
        Send {Enter} ; OK
        Sleep, 100 ;
        Send {Down} ; Jump to next folder
}
```

You have to edit the last one manually.

To know if a folder has been customized for Music, you can add the column 'Perceived type' in the explorer because I made the script assuming that the current customization is set to General Items.